# Generating a text training dataset from a grammar

Tags: dataset, text-mining, parsing, text, training

I want to generate documents based on a grammar to build a custom training database. What are the tools and techniques to generate random texts based on a given grammar.

More specifically, I would like to build a collection of texts with random 'sentences' and each one is a possible derivation (chosen randomly) from the grammar. I would like also to draw randomly the terminal symbols (the final words). I have looked into (python) nltk and have achieved some document generation, but the derivations chosen are not selected randomly.

Comment: Can you define grammar in this context?

Comment: Sure. I meant a format grammar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar and more specifically a context-free grammar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar ; For example, with this http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/generate.html you can generate sentences from a grammar, BUT they are somewhat drawn in a graph-traversal order, I would like to generate randomly (with uniform distribution over all possible derivations, if possible)

Comment: Uniform distribution is a problem if the grammar defines a potentially infinite output. Often generators will limit repeated segments for this reason.

Comment: Indeed. Let's say that my grammar generates a finite number of possible derivations (including terminals which are a finite set in my case).